# how to write per-channel attribute in sysfs

Tags: linux, networking, attributes, driver, sysfs

I am going to write a network device driver, which supports multiple channels.

Now, I am going to write the some counters (such as bytes/packets transferred) of this channel to `sysfs`.

For example, this device opens 8 channels, then, I would like to have sysfs like this:

```
/sys/devices/mynetdev/channel_0/
______________________________/bytes_egress
/sys/devices/mynetdev/channel_1/
______________________________/bytes_egress
/sys/devices/mynetdev/channel_2/
______________________________/bytes_egress
...
```

Questions:

1. How to create the attribute group so that I have one folder per channel?
2. Looks like I need to associate the attribute group before device registering. Then when do I update those attributes? Updating the attribute may impact the network performance?
3. How does the "attribute" work? For example, when user query the sysfs from `cat` command, does it issue command to driver to get attribute updated? Or my driver will keep updating the attribute and `cat` command just query the value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

set .modified field of iio_chan_spec to 1. Modifiers are specified using .channel2 field of the same iio_chan_spec structure and are used to indicate a physically unique characteristic of the channel such as its direction or spectral response. For example, a light sensor can have two channels, one for infrared light and one for both infrared and visible light.